# Set up a PHP OAuth Provider

Tags: php, oauth, oauth-provider

Alright I am trying to set up an OAuth Provider in PHP, but I just cannot get the hang of it.  I've been referenced to [this page](http://toys.lerdorf.com/archives/55-Writing-an-OAuth-Provider-Service.html) a number of times, but I cannot wrap my head around it.  Could someone help me out, step by step, or reference me to a more direct guide?  Thank you very much.

Comment: http://www.freeklijten.nl/home/2011/10/19/Writing-an-OAuth-Provider-in-PHP That might be of help as well

Answer (score 15, accepted):

http://djpate.com/2011/01/13/how-to-write-a-complete-oauth-provider-in-php5
thast a pretty good tutorial to get a clue on the provider side

Comment: An associate of mine showed me that link a little bit ago, and I do have to agree that it is a pretty good tutorial.

Comment: Darn you, past. It's 404ing here in the future.

Comment: Looks like djpate.com is down. Here's the time machine: http://web.archive.org/web/20121114041708/http://djpate.com/2011/01/13/how-to-write-a-complete-oauth-provider-in-php5/

Answer (score 0):

Pate's is good and here is another one by Rasmus:

http://toys.lerdorf.com/archives/55-Writing-an-OAuth-Provider-Service.html

Comment: This was the URL that the OP posted as not helping him :(

Answer (score -2):

I usually use the Zend_OAuth component (the whole 2 times ive implemented it, haha). The [manual](http://framework.zend.com/manual/en/zend.oauth.introduction.html) has some pretty clear instructions. This [tutorial](http://webhole.net/2010/02/19/step-by-step-zend-oauth-tutorial/) for it might also be helpful.

Comment: That's oAuth Consumer, not Provider. I'm looking for the same thing =), I'll post if I find anything.

Comment: Yet another person directed to this and getting a consumer not a provider. Even the OAuth site directs you to a consumer for CakePHP, this is getting silly - anyone got any help for this one?