# Pure PHP OAuth Provider

Tags: php, oauth, oauth-provider

Is there some code out there (under BSD or similar license preferably) that implements provider support for OAuth without needing PECL OAuth extension? Zend Framework's Zend_Oauth is pretty good, but it is only the consumer side. So I wonder if there's something like that but for doing the other side (i.e. making OAuth server).

Note that I'm not looking for how to do that with pecl/oauth - this I already have, see for example, [Set up a PHP OAuth Provider](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/3454063/set-up-a-php-oauth-provider) - but unfortunately not all people can install PECL extensions, so I'm looking for some solution that would reduce requirements.

Comment: This is not a duplicate! I specifically asked for *pure PHP* solution, and the linked question discusses PECL solution and asks how to implement the provider, while I *know* how to implement a provider using PECL solution, but looking for *other* solution in pure PHP. Those are completely different questions and I specifically noted it in the question!

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Have you taken a look at http://pear.php.net/package/HTTP_OAuth/?

Answer (score 2):

I've ended up making some implementation for Oauth provider for Zend Framework, which can be seen here: https://github.com/smalyshev/Zend_OAuth_Provider

I'll improve it if time permits but it works for me right now.