# PHP oAuth2 Provider

Tags: php, service, oauth-2.0, provider, oauth-provider

I am trying to find a tutorial on how to build an oAuth2 Provider with PHP. I googled about it and no results came up. Exists out there any guides on how to do this? Or something like a library that can help me implement an oAuth2 Service Provider with PHP?

Answer (score 4, accepted):

https://github.com/bshaffer/oauth2-server-php this will be helpfull for you to get idea.

Answer (score 2):

I've been looking for the same thing for a while now, but I haven't found much.  oAuth2 is still [in draft](https://datatracker.ietf.org/doc/html/draft-ietf-oauth-v2). The current version as of this writing is 30.

The best things I'v found are a Google Code project that supports version 9 of the spec, which could be fairly outdated.  You can find that project [here](http://code.google.com/p/oauth2-php/).

I have also found this article on how to write it yourself, though I haven't looked at the post in sometime - [How to write a complete OAuth Provider in PHP5](http://djpate.com/2011/01/13/how-to-write-a-complete-oauth-provider-in-php5/).

It looks like there is some movement with the [Zend Framework 2](http://framework.zend.com/zf2) which looks hopeful.  It looks like an RFC was in June, 2012: [RFC - OAuth 2.0](http://framework.zend.com/wiki/display/ZFDEV2/RFC+-+OAuth+2.0)

I'm certainly anxious for something to use myself.

Similar questions have been asked as well for reference which include the links to projects referenced above:

- [Set up a PHP OAuth Provider](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/3454063/set-up-a-php-oauth-provider)
- [Are there OAuth 2 server side PHP or Java implementations?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/4875420/are-there-oauth-2-server-side-php-or-java-implementations)

Hope that helps!

Anyone find/use/recommend an oAuth2 provider library/class?

Comment: The "How to write a complete OAuth Provider in PHP5" link above is dead. But the magic of the way back machine has a cached version: http://web.archive.org/web/20120730091300/http://djpate.com/2011/01/13/how-to-write-a-complete-oauth-provider-in-php5

Comment: Good catch Dan, I haven't checked on this in a while.  I use the Wayback Machine quite often when I find the site is no longer available.